# Symfony2 : doctrine orm ignore if I change table name

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I made a new Entity called Comment using the command : **php app/console doctrine:generate:entity**

I changed its name in the Comment.php file like this :

```
/**
 * Comment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_comment")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mysite\BlogBundle\Entity\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mysite\BlogBundle\Entity\Article")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $article;
```

When I try the command **php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql**, it returns me "CREATE TABLE Comment ...". So it ignores my changes ?

I just cleared cache and tried again, nothing changes... Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have an opcode cache like APC or something like that running? Maybe you could try clearing that too

Comment: Nothing special running. It worked fine for my other tables before I tried this today. Could it come from my ManyToOne relationship ?
It's for now my only table using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `app/console cache:clear` I would recommend trying `rm -rf app/cache/*` instead and see if that fixes your issue.  I run into this problem occasionally and this usually works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried and it doesn't solve my problem. Still creating a Comment table, not a blog_comment... dammit ! :p

Comment: Maybe try dropping the database and doing a fresh `doctrine:database:create` and a `doctrine:schema:create`? If that doesn't work... then ... ? lol

Comment: I just made a try. It created the database again with Comment table, but now it does not create my other old tables... what the hell ?!

Comment: Did you use the app/console entity generator to make the entity or just an empty file and manually created the class?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I made a dumb mistake while creating the entity running the command. I may have set the configuration format to "yml" and not "annotation", which is the format of my other tables... grrrr ! Now I can't make any update because I just removed my yml entity and doctrine says it's missing.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, that would do it. Doctrine hates when you try to use multiple configuration formats.

Comment: At least, I learnt from my own mistake ! Sorry for the time lost :/